# GTK theme, Window theme, and icon theme for Guest Account

Tags: themes, icons, gtk, guest-session

Hi I want to change only the gtk, window and icon theme for my guest account.

I looked at the [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) guide but the first section I did not understand how to apply it to my need and the second section basically was explaining how to copy a whole accounts settings when I just want three little things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some more digging and found how to change the gtk, window, and icon theme with terminal commands. This is a big find because it allowed me to add them to the auto.sh script mentioned in the first section and third point at the CustomizeGuestSession guide. Here is what I did in Ubuntu 14.04.

I opened a terminal and entered
    sudo gedit /usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh

Then I added just above the section that says "# disable screen locking"

```
# set gtk icon and winodow theme
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "gtk-theme name"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'icon-theme name'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "window-theme name"
```

I then made sure to copy my .themes folder from my home folder over to /etc/skel

Hope this helps others as well!

Comment: Instead of modifying  `/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh` you should put all your commands into the file `/etc/guest-session/auto.sh` (create the folder and the file if they don't exist).   `/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh` is part of the `lightdm` package will be be overwritten if the package is updated.